SolidJS Store : updating an object let another object with the same data being updated
I have a context/store with two objects (settings and defaultSettings) that are populated while fetching the data from the Database with createResource and I am adding disabled property to the 2 first persons.
I need to compare settings and defaultSettings in every step of the code so I can activate or deactivate a button. But then the problem I have is, that if I am updating a property in settings later, it is also updated in defaultSettings.
Could you help me to fix that problem?
Here a part of the code with an example of data:
const data = { settings: 
     { persons: [
             { name: "a", firstName: "b"}, 
             { name: "c", firstName: "d"},
             { name: "e", firstName: "f"}, 
             { name: "g", firstName: "h"}
       ], 
       address: { zipCode: 12345, number: 342 }
    }
}
const disabledPerson = (settings) => {
    settings.persons.map((person, index) => {
            let entry = (index ==0 || index==1) ? ({...person, disabled: false}): ({...person, disabled: true})
            entriesafter.push(entr)
    
        setState("settings", "person", entriesafter)
        setState("defaultSettings", "person", entriesafter)
            
        }
    )
}
const getDefaultSettings = async () => {
    const settings = {
        method: "GET",
    }
    try {
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8083/getSettings', settings);
        const data = await response.json();
        setState("defaultSettings", state.defaultSettings = data[0].settings)
        setState("settings", state.settings = data[0].settings)
        disabledPerson(data[0].settings)

        return data[0].settings
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}
const [defaultSettings] = createResource<settings[]>(getDefaultSettings)
return (
    <TextField value= {state.settings.address.zipCode} onChange={(e)=> {setState("settings", "address", e.currentTarget.value)/></>
)


If you have server-side-rendering (e.g. using Astro or Solid Start), it's best to fetch the defaultSettings already on the server, to avoid a loading waterfall...

regarding your current code: where does setState come from? and where in the code do you need defaultSettings again so that it's a problem that it's updated? Please post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

I am using a context/store.
const [state, setState] = createStore({
defaultSettings: {},
settings: {},
})
<SettingsContext.Provider value={{state, setState}}>

</SettingsContext.Provider>

Here is an example of the code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/solidjs-template-9zzjcg?file=src%2Fcontext%2FSettingsContext.tsx,src%2FApp.tsx,src%2FSettings.tsx

@Y.Coding You don't need context API for this code as you can directly access any value from the parent scope in SolidJS. It seems your are not following SolidJS API or I could not get your intention, especially with the resource API. Why would you update state in the fetcher function.

It is hard to say anything without seeing the actual code or a working demo, but if I understand you correctly you have two related signals and updating one overwrites the other one because signals are updated consecutively.
If that is the case, you need to batch update both signals at the same time, so that values do not get overwritten: https://www.solidjs.com/docs/latest#batch
batch(() => {
  setA(valueA);
  setB(valueB);
});

However, if you are using stores, stores are batched by default. You should not have such problems.

Thank you for the tip. Can you give me an example please?

If you share a working demo via stackblitz or github I can take a look.

Actually I am using two stores. I will post a working demo

Here is a part of the code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/solidjs-template-9zzjcg?file=src%2Fcontext%2FSettingsContext.tsx,src%2FApp.tsx,src%2FSettings.tsx

It is a bit hard to diagnose the exact issue, but below I’ve included an example code snippet that might help you address the issue you're facing and give you an idea of how to manage the state.
const data = {
  settings: {
    persons: [
      { name: 'a', firstName: 'b' },
      { name: 'c', firstName: 'd' },
      { name: 'e', firstName: 'f' },
      { name: 'g', firstName: 'h' },
    ],
    address: { zipCode: 12345, number: 342 },
  },
};

const getDefaultSettings = async () => {
  try {
    // TODO: Fetch settings from API
    return data.settings;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};

const disabledPerson = (settings) => {
  const modifiedPersons = settings.persons.map((person, index) => {
    const disabled = index == 0 || index == 1;
    return { ...person, disabled };
  });

  return {
    ...settings,
    persons: modifiedPersons,
  };
};

const Settings: Component = () => {
  const { state, setState } = useContext(SettingsContext);
  const [defaultSettings] = createResource(getDefaultSettings);

  createEffect(() => {
    const settings = defaultSettings();
    if (!settings) return;

    const modifiedSettings = disabledPerson(settings);

    // Just for the sake of demonstration,
    // update 'settings' with the modified version
    // and update 'defaultSettings' with the non-modified version
    setState('settings', modifiedSettings);
    setState('defaultSettings', settings);
  });

  return (
    <>
      <div>Settings:</div>
      <For each={state.settings?.persons}>
        {(person) => (
          <div>
            {person.name} {person.disabled ? 'Disabled' : 'Enabled'}
          </div>
        )}
      </For>
      <div>Default settings:</div>
      <For each={state.defaultSettings?.persons}>
        {(person) => (
          <div>
            {person.name} {person.disabled ? 'Disabled' : 'Enabled'}
          </div>
        )}
      </For>
      <TextField
        value={state.settings.address?.zipCode ?? '0'}
        onChange={(e) =>
          setState('settings', 'address', 'zipCode', e.currentTarget.value)
        }
      />
    </>
  );
};


Thank you a lot for your answer! I will debug my code again to check where the error is exactly.
